# Android writing Data to Edittext

Tags: android, json, arraylist, tostring

When Im writing the result into a TextView It show me like this:

> ChampionList[[[Annie],[Blitzcrank],[Cassiopeia],[Corki],[Lucian]]]

I dont know how to dont show the array " [] ".Can Anyone help me please?

Thats the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ChampionList {

    private ArrayList<Champion> champions;

    public ArrayList<Champion> getChampions() {
        return champions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {


        return "ChampionList [" + champions + "]";

    }

    public void setChampions(ArrayList<Champion> champions) {
        this.champions = champions;
    }



}
```

Champion class:

```
package src.jriot.objects;

public class Champion {


    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "[" + name + "]";
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code where champions are added via `setChampions()`, please?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can suggest one workaround. Replace all brackets using `replaceAll` method.

Comment: `return "ChampionList [" + champions + "]";` the brackets are there. Just remove them.

Comment: Removing the brackets dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (Iterator<Champion> iterator = champions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
       Champion champion = (Champion) iterator.next();
       sb.append(champion.toString() + ",");

}
String result = sb.toString();
return result.substring(0,result.length()-1);


}
```

You may also need to override the toString function in your Champion class.

Assuming `Champion` class looks like this:

```
public class Champion {
    private String championName;
    //The Tostring() method can look like this
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return championName;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tryed yours and now is [Annie][Blitzcrank][Cassiopeia]

Comment: It worked :), thank you very much!!. One question, now If I want to separate it by "," How can I do it?

Comment: @Virusble I edited the answer. See the `toString` function in ChampionsList.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString() method to create your own presentable output which will iterate through your arraylist and adding the elements to a string. Like so:

```
String championsList = "";

for(int i = 0; i< champions.size(); i++)
{
    championsList += championsList.get(i) + ", ";
}

System.out.println(championsList);
```